# Pointer assignment in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a simple struct to hold two `const double`s.

```
struct Scale {
    const double SCALE_X, SCALE_Y;

    Scale(double, double);
};

Scale::Scale(double sx, double sy) :
SCALE_X(sx), SCALE_Y(sy) {
}
```

I have this function that returns a boolean as confirmation, and sets the passed `oscale` pointer to whatever calculated value found inside.

```
bool FindSequence(Scale* oscale) {
    // ...
    *oscale = Scale(sx, sy);
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

In use:

```
Scale *scale;
if (FindSequence(scale)) {
    std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
}
```

Compile log:

```
photon.cpp:286:14: error: use of deleted function 'photon::Scale& photon::Scale::operator=(photon::Scale&&)'
      *oscale = Scale(sx, sy);
              ^
In file included from photon.h:5:0,
                 from photon.cpp:4:
globals.h:76:9: note: 'photon::Scale& photon::Scale::operator=(photon::Scale&&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  struct Scale {
         ^
globals.h:76:9: error: non-static const member 'const double photon::Scale::SCALE_X', can't use default assignment operator
globals.h:76:9: error: non-static const member 'const double photon::Scale::SCALE_Y', can't use default assignment operator
```

Do I have to override the operator=? Is it because the Scale struct is immutable? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The compiler cannot implicitly define the assignment- or move- operator if the class contains sub-objects which cannot be assigned (or moved), like `const`-qualified objects or references. And whatever you try to get around it will cause UB (aside from removing the qualifiers).

Comment: `Scale *scale; if (FindSequence(scale)) {` would invoke UB if you dereference the pointer, as you do in `*oscale = Scale(sx, sy);`. (Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is UB.) You mean this: `Scale scale; if (FindSequence(&scale)) {`. But what you probably *really* mean is `bool FindSequence(Scale & oscale)` and `Scale scale; if (FindSequence(scale)) {`.

Comment: Also, declare the `SCALE_X` and `SCALE_Y` members non-const. If you have a `Scale` object then you can change them, but if you have a `const Scale` object then you can't. Forcing them read-only is bad practice; if the consumer wants a read-only `Scale` object then they can just declare it `const`.

Comment: Got it, do I have to declare a second constructor so that `Scale scale;` does not throw an error or is there another way around not having to actually create the object?

Comment: Why would default constructing a `Scale` throw an error?  Unless it is doing something we don't know about.  Maybe you should post the default `Scale` constructor.

Comment: I created a constructor that takes two doubles, does this not remove the default constructor? `error: no matching function for call to 'photon::Scale::Scale()'
   Scale scale;`

Comment: @John You don't even have one, so yes, you would have to define one. A reasonable implementation might do the same thing as `Scale(0, 0)`.

Comment: @John - You need to declare a default constructor.  Also, by convention, `CAPITALIZED_NAMES` are usually reserved for macros and constants, not member variable names.

Comment: @John I've consolidated all of my comments into an answer. Give it a read if you are confused by the comments and see if the answer phrases things a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here.  I'll go over them one by one.

```
const double SCALE_X, SCALE_Y;
```

This is the primary source of your problem.  The compiler won't generate a copy constructor or copy assignment operator if the class has `const` members; you would have to generate them yourself.

However, I don't think that these members should even be `const`.  If someone has a `Scale` object then they should be able to change its value, but if they have a `const Scale` object then they *won't* be able to, because all (non-`mutable`) data members "become" `const` when accessed on a `const` object.

In other words, let the *consumer* of the class decide if they want instances to be read-only; non-`const` `Scale` objects *should* be mutable!

With this one change, the compiler will be able to generate sane a copy constructor and a sane copy assignment operator, so that particular error will go away.

However, you do have another error here:

```
Scale *scale;
if (FindSequence(scale)) {
```

You are passing in an uninitialized pointer.  As soon as `FindSequence()` dereferences this pointer, undefined behavior is invoked and your program will likely crash.

Typically you would do this using references:

```
bool FindSequence(Scale & oscale) {
```

Then the calling code becomes this (just remove the `*`):

```
Scale scale;
if (FindSequence(scale)) {
```

But to do *this* you will need a default constructor.  A sane option would be to have it initialize the members to zero:

```
Scale::Scale() : SCALE_X(0), SCALE_Y(0) { }
```

(Alternatively, you could just do `Scale scale(0, 0);` instead.)

Apply these three changes and the compiler should get past these issues.  (It may, of course, run into other issues, but these changes will fix the ones in your question.)

Comment: Thanks, my main reasoning for the const fields was coming from more of a Java background where `final` objects didn't make the internals immutables. TIL, thanks!

Comment: @John No problem. Note that in C++, methods can be `const` too, and you cannot call non-`const` methods on `const` objects. Inside of `const` objects, the `this` pointer points to a `const` object. This means that you can publish different interfaces depending on whether or not the object being invoked on is `const`!  (For example, standard library containers will return `iterator` from `begin()` if the object is *not* `const`, but will return `const_iterator` if the object *is* `const`.)

Comment: So any method that does not change the state of the object should be `const` or you won't be able to use it from a `const` object. (`void foo();` versus `void foo() const;` -- if both exist then which one is selected depends on the `const`-ness of the object on which it is invoked.)

Comment: I see. What is the functional difference between an `iterator` and `const_iterator`? Are these separate only because they have to?

Comment: const iterator operates on const objects as well as non const objects whereas iterator works on non const objects only. Preferably you should always resort to iterator unless there is need to do otherwise...

Comment: @ravi Actually, I usually do the opposite -- I use const iterators unless I need to change the objects in the collection. But that's a topic for a different question.

Comment: @cdhowie Actually its a matter of what you are trying to accomplish with iterators. Some algorothmdont digest const iterator so you need to resort to conversion which could be inefficient for some iterator categories. I dont want to delve deeper into this as it would be out of scope for this topic...

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to note here

First compiler wont generate assigment operator for class for which it doesnt know how assignment would be done i.e class containing const and reference members.

Second you are trying to dereference uninitialized pointer which is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add, as an extra note, that if you *did* really want to have `const` members and an initialisation function then the way to do it is with placement-new:

```
bool FindSequence(Scale* oscale) {
    // ...
    oscale = new (oscale) Scale(sx, sy);
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

This uses your `Scale` constructor to initialise the pointed-at object, not the assignment operator, avoiding the need for a compiler-generated operator.

As others have pointed out, your code then runs into undefined behaviour because you pass an uninitialised pointer to the `FindSequence` function.  What you probably meant is something like this:

```
Scale scale(0.0, 0.0);
if (FindSequence(&scale)) {
    std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
}
```

Some would argue that this is a bad idea because it allows you to change a `const` object after initialisation, though, and I'd expect that your compiler may attempt optimisations on the assumption that those `const double` members don't change, so you may see strange behaviour if you try this.